# I can only receive file using bluetooth in Xubuntu

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, bluetooth

I have installed Xubuntu 12.04.1 on my machine. I can only receive file using bluetooth from my cellphone and i can not send file from my machine to cellphone (with `Send File to Device` action in bluetooth applet), It starts sending but after some minute it says that "Request timeout, Error occurred while sending file 1.jpg". 
I don not know why?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be an issue of your cellphone (make?) - has it object exchange profile (OBEX) OPP or FTP implemented? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange

Comment: I do not think so because when i had Ubuntu 12.04, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. In default ubuntu desktop bluetooth was working perfectly. So in xubuntu, I removed blueman (which is the current bluetooth manager of xubuntu 12.04) and installed gnome-bluetooth. After a restart, gnome bluetooth manager was present in the top panel. It worked perfectly. I guess there is a bug in blueman packages.

Comment: setting Bluetooth-accept-files=always did not work for me, but this solution did! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

That can be the bluetooth conf is not set to ALWAYS no dconf.

Open dconf and search for bluetooth

will open a bluetooth config and in my pc i mark all options and i get bluetooth receive and send files normaly.

Comment: the options is Bluetooth-accept-files = always, put it in your configuration i dconf to work as well!!